Subclassing Pandas Series without losing original methods
I'm trying to implement my subclass of pd.Series, but original pd.Series methods don't work as expected and return Nan
class Subclass(pd.Series):
    # see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TimeSeries, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if not isinstance(self.index, pd.DatetimeIndex):
            self.index = pd.to_datetime(self.index)

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        """
        see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html
        #extending-subclassing-pandas
        """
        def f(*args, **kwargs):
            return Subclass(**kwargs).__finalize__(self)
        return f

    @property
    def _constructor_expanddim(self):
        def f(*args, **kwargs):
            return Subclass(**kwargs).__finalize__(self)
        return f

s = Subclass(data=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-01 15:00:00', '2024-01-01 15:05:00', '2024-01-01 15:10:00', '2024-01-01 15:15:00', '2024-01-01 15:20:00']))

s.copy returns Subclass([])
s.autocorr(2) returns nan
s.diff() returns Subclass(data=[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN], index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-01 15:00:00', '2024-01-01 15:05:00', '2024-01-01 15:10:00', '2024-01-01 15:15:00', '2024-01-01 15:20:00']))

How should I implement _constructor to pass arguments correctly?

Just register a series accessor. That's the easiest way. Could you Gove an example of what you want the subclass to achieve that pandas does not achieve?

I want it have an additional property. I use _metadata = ['property'], but I faced the error in the post before that. What is the series accessor?

Additional property is not an issue. What do you want this property to store? What other manipulations do you want the series to do?
